# A word for the resulting piece of a promotion?

Tags: pawn-promotion

I'm looking for a word that represents the piece after the promotion. In a chemical reaction there are the reactants and the products. Is there an equivalent word for product in promotion?
(In case I haven't make it clear: after a8=Q, is there a word for that queen?)

**Edit**: I was looking for a generic term (preferably one word) for the resulting *piece*, not a specific type like queen or knight.

**Summarizing some suggestions**
The following suggestions are from comments and answers (thank you all) at the time I'm editing this: "promoted piece", "promotee", and "new piece".

Comment: "Promoted queen" "new queen" "second queen".

Comment: @SmallChess But I need a more generic term for all pieces. "Promoted piece" is an option but a single word would be better (if such word exists).

Comment: I've personally never heard this described by a single word, and am not aware that such a word exists.  The term "promoted piece" is what I'm familiar with.  But language is fluid - if there's no word that represents the concept you're trying to describe, you always have the option of just making one up and trying to get people to adopt it.  ;-)

Comment: I believe the term "promoted piece" is quite standard in the literature of chess problems, where, as I understand it, the presence of such pieces in the diagram is considered an esthetic flaw.

Comment: The obvious one-word term is "promotee". I've never seen anyone use it in chess, but it fits the dictionary definition, so feel free to use it if you must.

Comment: @itub Thanks for your suggestion. I would consider a [verb]-er and [verb]-ee relationship to contain two entities with one acting on another: an employer employs an employee or the employee is been employed by the employer. But promotion does not have this relationship (the pawn does not promote the resulting piece nor is the resulting piece been promoted by the pawn).

Comment: @Eric well it is I who promote my pawn. Therefore, I am the promoter while the pawn is the promotee.

Comment: If one wants some Latin-ish grammar coolness, the promoted piece could be the "promotand". :)

Comment: It might make sense to ask this question in the context of shogi. Piece promotion in shogi is similar to piece promotion in western chess, with pawns and most pieces being able to promote to gold general ; however, captured pieces have a second life in shogi, and when a promoted piece is captured by the opponent, it loses its promotion. This means that a pawn-promoted-to-gold-general is not equivalent to an unpromoted-gold-general. Because if your opponent captures an unpromoted gold general, they get a gold general; but if your opponent captures a promoted pawn, they get a pawn.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you are after, if you are looking for a generic term describing a piece that was added in the game during the play then you seem to be after something that is not embedded in the game. There is no such word and there cannot be any because if there was such a word it would suggest that the new piece is somehow different from an equivalent piece that was there at the beginning of the game. But that is not the case the piece into which the pawn is promoted is absolutely equivalent to another piece of the same name and colour.

Occasionally it may be useful to refer to a piece that has just been added (but this you seem not to want to do). There are several reasonable suggestions in the comments I will just add that the Laws of chess use "the new piece" for this purpose (as in "... and the effect of the new piece is immediate" or "...when the player's hand has released the new piece on the square of promotion...", articles 3.7.5.3 and 4.7.3, respectively).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am looking for a generic term describing the new piece. I suspected that such a word does not exist but I needed a knowledgeable person to confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't reckon any terms describing such things, why don't we create them?

> New born Queen = Princess
>   A young Horse/Knight = Foal
>   A junior Bishop = Suffragan
>   A smaller Rook = Crow

I know I will face a lot of disagreement, and I'm not sure if people will ever use these stupid terms.

Comment: Aside from the fact that these are actually not what I'm looking for (see the edited question), your suggestions are awesome.

Comment: Fxb4, Pxa4+, Sa2#, Cb1#